# Use static variable instead of implementing IBinder for Android service?

Tags: android, service, xamarin.android

The Android docs give information about how to implement a started service and how to deal with a bound service. However they are not really precise about hybrid services.

Let's assume I have a local service which I start and later bind to. I want to keep the service alive all times (maybe it is collecting location information).

The idea behind the hybrid service is that at some point in my app I must communicate with the service to maybe pull data from it.

What's the advantage of implementing a `Binder` for that purpose? According to the docs this binder would store a [reference to my service or expose public methods](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder) which talk to the service.

Why would I not simply have a static variable in my service and assign the service (`this`) to it in the constructor? I could return `null` from `onBind()`, and not bother about `ServiceConnection`.

I get the `Binder` requirement for pure bound services but what about the hybrid local ones? What do I miss here?

Comment: if you would return `null` from `onBind()` so probably there is no need for calling `bindService` and bound `Service` gains another value for "not to be killed" component: "The Android system will force-stop a service only when memory is low and it must recover system resources for the activity that has user focus. If **the service is bound** to an activity that has user focus, then it's less likely to be killed,"

Comment: That's an argument to use the binding system I did not think of. My question is more targeted against technical implications of not using the binder.

Comment: for a local service that is always `started` in theory you could do that, using a static variable, but why to risk? also i think that `ServiceConnection#onServiceDisconnected` could be useful in some use cases